# Get null for DEFAULT SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I have a table with candidate details which insert base64 image as the profile picture. When I getting huge number of candidate list from the table the profile picture is taking too much space. I have a default base64 image as profile pic for those doesn't upload profile pics. What I want is take null if the profile picture is DEFAULT for the candidate.
My  Query is something simple like this,

```
select 
    Name,
    DOB, 
    case when profilepic is default then NULL else profile pic 
from candidates
```

The code is showing error for using default but works fine when I use
null in place of DEFAULT

Comment: `IS DEFAULT` isn't valid syntax. What are you *actually* trying to achieve here?

Comment: Also your `CASE` expression is missing an `END`.

Comment: getting null value with the candidate if the profilepic is default value in the table or else get the profile picture

Comment: Not easy. You'll need to inspect the `CONSTRAINT` in the `sys` objects, see if the value matches, and then return `NULL` instead.

Comment: can't i declare a @default with the value and match with that ?

Comment: You could define a variable and then use an equality expression, yes.

Comment: the case is the dafault pic is taking much space for bigger list taking MB's for the default pics

Comment: You can set to null all the default pic (less space used on DB).

Then, in your code, if the value is null you load the default pic.

Comment: okay that works too thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something along the lines of:

```
select 
Name
,DOB
,case when profilepic = (SELECT COLUMN_DEFAULT FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS  WHERE COLUMN_NAME='profilepic' and TABLE_NAME='candidates') then NULL else profilepic END 
from candidates
```

You might need to parse the suqbuery a bit.

Comment: will this take much time to complete ?

Comment: YMMV, depends on how much data you have in you DB. Check the explain plan beforehand or check a subset of data first using TOP.

Comment: @KERALAZEUZ Can't imagine it would make much difference, the subquery is not correlated so it will probably be pushed through as a single outer reference. You could always assign it to a variable first if you're worried. Note that this is not going to work if the default is anything other than a literal value, and even if it is, you still need to parse the SQL out of the constraint

Comment: @KERALAZEUZ . . . You have to be careful with this approach.  The default value is surfaced as a string in the `information_schema` view, which can cause subtle issues when compared to data stored as other types.  That says, you don't have much choice.

Answer (score 0):

Should be more efficient like this :

```
SELECT Name, DOB,
       CASE WHEN profilepic = T.COLUMN_DEFAULT 
                THEN NULL 
            ELSE profilepic 
       END 
FROM   candidates
       CROSS APPLY (SELECT COLUMN_DEFAULT 
                    FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS  
                    WHERE  COLUMN_NAME = 'profilepic' and 
                           TABLE_NAME = 'candidates' and
                           TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo' ) AS T
```

Assuming that your table is in SQL Server database default schema (dbo).